# Can't get the javascript from twitter bootstrap accordian to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow the instructions on this site: http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/

I have followed the instructions, and even copied and pasted the exact code. Can you tell me what's going wrong? I have verified that all the code is located in the proper directory. Here is an image of what's displaying on my site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Z5n.png

Here's my code, the CSS is added in the header and is not in the code below:

```
<div id="body">
        <div class="row-fluid breadcrumbs margin-bottom-30">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="pull-left">Book Now!</h1>

            </div><!--/container-->
        </div><!--/breadcrumbs-->

    <div class="container">     
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span9">


        <div class="row-fluid acc-wizard">
          <div class="span3" style="padding-left: 2em;">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
              Follow the steps below to add an accordion wizard to your web page.
            </p>
            <ol class="acc-wizard-sidebar">
              <li class="acc-wizard-todo"><a href="#prerequisites">Prerequisites</a></li>
              <li class="acc-wizard-todo"><a href="#addwizard">Add Wizard</a></li>
              <li class="acc-wizard-todo"><a href="#adjusthtml">Adjust HTML</a></li>
              <li class="acc-wizard-todo"><a href="#viewpage">Release</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="span9">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion-demo">
              <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#prerequisites">
                    Install Bootstrap and jQuery
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="prerequisites" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                  <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <form id="form-prerequisites">
                      <p>
                        The accordion wizard depends on two other open source packages:
                        <ul>
                          <li>The Bootstrap framework, available <a href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html">here</a>.
                          <li>The jQuery javascript library, available <a href="http://jquery.com">here</a>.
                        </ul>
                        Note that Bootstrap itself depends on jQuery for its interactive
                        components, so if you're using Bootstrap you probably already have
                        jQuery as well.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        You'll include the CSS styles for Bootstrap in the
                        <code>&lt;head&gt;</code> of your HTML file, for example:
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt;<!--
                      --></pre>
                      <p>
                        and you'll include jQuery and Bootstrap javascript files at the
                        end of your <code>&lt;body&gt;</code> section, for example:
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<!--
                      --></pre>
                    </form>
                  </div> <!--/.accordion-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /#prerequisites -->
              </div> <!-- /.accordion-group -->

              <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#addwizard">
                    Add Accordion Wizard
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="addwizard" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                  <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <form id="form-addwizard">
                      <p>
                        If you haven't already found it, the source code for the
                        accordion wizard is available on github
                        <a href="https://github.com/sathomas/acc-wizard">here</a>.
                        There are two main folders, <code>/src</code> and
                        <code>/release</code>.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        There are two different ways to add the accordion wizard to
                        your pages. The simplest approach is just to add the CSS and
                        javascript files from the <code>/release</code> folder
                        directly in your HTML without modifying them:
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;link href="css/acc-wizard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"&gt;<!--
                      --></pre>
                      <p>
                        and
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;script src="js/acc-wizard.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<!--
                      --></pre>
                      <p>
                        The release styles for the accordion wizard are based on
                        Bootstrap's default styles. If you've tweaked the Bootstrap
                        styles (e.g. by changing the link color), you'll want to
                        make corresponding tweaks to <code>acc-wizard.min.css</code>.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        Alternatively, if you're building custom CSS and javascript,
                        then you might want to start with the files in the <code>/src</code>
                        folder and adapt them to your source code. The <code>/src</code>
                        folder contains a LESS file and uncompressed (and commented)
                        javascript. Note that the <code>acc-wizard.less</code> file
                        depends on variables defined in Bootstrap's <code>variables.less</code>
                        file.
                    </form>
                  </div> <!--/.accordion-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /#addwizard -->
              </div> <!-- /.accordion-group -->

              <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#adjusthtml">
                    Adjust Your HTML Markup
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="adjusthtml" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                  <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <form id="form-adjusthtml">
                      <p>
                        Now you can modify your HTML markup to activate the accordion
                        wizard. There are two parts to the markup&mdash;the collapsible
                        accordion itself and the task list. I prefer putting both in
                        the same <code>.row</code> with the task list taking up a
                        <code>.span3</code> and the accordion panels in a <code>.span9</code>,
                        but that's not a requirement.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        The accordion panel can be exactly as documented in the
                        <a href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse">Bootstrap example</a>,
                        but I think there's a problem with the Bootstrap implementation.
                        Specifically, the Bootstrap example only adds the class
                        <code>.in</code> to one of the accordion panels. That class
                        marks the panel as visible by default. The problem with only
                        having one panel visible by default is that users without
                        javascript will <strong>never</strong> be able to see the other
                        panels. Sure, that's a minority of users, but why make your
                        pages unworkable even for a small minority. Instead, I suggest
                        adding <code>.in</code> to all your <code>.collapse</code>
                        elements and have javascript code select only one to make
                        visible when it runs. The accordion wizard javascript will handle
                        that for you if you choose to use that approach.
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        The sidebar task list is nothing but a standard HTML ordered
                        list. The only required additions are adding the
                        <code>.acc-wizard-sidebar</code> class to the <code>&lt;ol&gt;</code>
                        element and <code>.acc-wizard-todo</code> to the individual list
                        items. If you want to indicate that some steps are already
                        complete, you can instead add the <code>.acc-wizard-completed</code>
                        class to the corresponding <code>&lt;li&gt;</code> elements.
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;ol class="acc-wizard-sidebar"&gt;
    <!--              -->  &lt;li class="acc-wizard-todo"&gt;&lt;a href="#prerequisites">Install Bootstrap and jQuery&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!--              -->  &lt;li class="acc-wizard-todo"&gt;&lt;a href="#addwizard">Add Accordion Wizard&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!--              -->  &lt;li class="acc-wizard-todo"&gt;&lt;a href="#adjusthtml">Adjust Your HTML Markup&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!--              -->  &lt;li class="acc-wizard-todo"&gt;&lt;a href="#viewpage">Test Your Page&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!--              -->&lt;/ol><!--
                      --></pre>
                      <p>
                        Finally, you'll want to active the wizard in your javascript.
                        That's nothing more than simply calling the plugin on an
                        appropriate selection.
                      </p>
                      <pre><!--
                      -->&lt;script&gt;
    <!--              -->    $(window).load(function() {
    <!--              -->        $(".acc-wizard").accwizard();
    <!--              -->    });
    <!--              -->&lt;/script&gt;<!--
                     --></pre>
                      <p>
                        The default options are probably fine for most uses, but
                        there are many customizations you can use when you activate
                        the wizard. Check out the documentation on
                        <a href="https://github.com/sathomas/acc-wizard">github</a>
                        for the details.
                      </p>
                    </form>
                  </div> <!--/.accordion-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /#adjusthtml -->
              </div> <!-- /.accordion-group -->

              <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-demo" href="#viewpage">
                    Test Your Page
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="viewpage" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                  <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <form id="viewpage">
                      <p>
                        Naturally, the last thing you'll want to do is test your
                        page with the accordion wizard. Once you've confirmed that
                        it's working as expected, release it on the world. Your
                        users will definitely appreciate the feedback and guidance
                        it gives to multi-step and complex tasks on your web site.
                      </p>
                    </form>
                  </div> <!--/.accordion-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /#viewpage -->
              </div> <!-- /.accordion-group -->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/acc-wizard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          function onNext(parent, panel) {
            hash = "#" + panel.id;
            $(".acc-wizard-sidebar",$(parent))
                .children("li")
                .children("a[href='" + hash + "']")
                .parent("li")
                .removeClass("acc-wizard-todo")
                .addClass("acc-wizard-completed");
          }
          $(window).load(function() {
            $(".acc-wizard").accwizard({onNext: onNext});
          })
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you not forget add bootstrap.js to your code?

Comment: I added it in the edit. it's just elsewhere in the code. sorry.

Comment: `acc_wizard` used probably bootstrap and jquery so this should be as last not first.

Comment: so i should put the js files before that?

Comment: Look on my answer. This is order from `acc_wizard` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is important! You add these libraries but in wrong order. Here is correct:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/acc-wizard.min.js"></script>
```

And fix that errors first!:

```
GET http://shield.sitelock.com/shield/maidsinmemphis.com 403 (Forbidden) index.php:363
GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/elasticslides/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) index.php:25
GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/css/acc-wizard.min.css 404 (Not Found) index.php:31
GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/elasticslides/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js 404 (Not Found) index.php:387
GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/elasticslides/js/jquery.eislideshow.js 404 (Not Found) index.php:387
GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/js/acc-wizard.min.js 404 (Not Found) index.php:387
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accwizard'
```

Comment: I added all three like that and there's still no change... would you like to see the source code of the entire page?

Comment: Yes sure. It will be the best way. put link here to your site if it is online.

Comment: 1. Remove these two first scripts and move acc_wizard after this on bottom of your page: `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: 2. Move this `$(".acc-wizard").accwizard({onNext: onNext});` to inside your `$(function() {}` on bottom of page together with `onNext` function

Comment: What errors? Can we talk on another medium? I updated the site and it works better, but still not 100%.

Comment: Press F12 if you using Chrome. You missing css: `GET http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/assets/css/acc-wizard.min.css 404 (Not Found)` Also look on my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you not forgot about this?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm also including those in another portion:

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>